# Sort an arraylist by an object property using the order of another arraylist with same type property in Java

Tags: java, sorting, collections, arraylist

I have 2 arraylists contained objects like this:

1st arraylist contains string and double : [a  1.1, b  1.2, d  0.4, g 1.9, f 0.5  and so on...]

2nd arraylist contains string, double and int : [b  0.1  2, f  1.1  5, g  2.3  1, a  1.1  2 and so on...]

2nd arraylist may contain either same or greater or lesser number of items in it than 1st one but all its string property values will be any of those which are only present in 1st one's string property.

All I need to sort the 2nd arraylist by the string property according to the order of 1st arraylist string property. 1st arraylist is already in order and if I sort the 2nd one then the expected output will be:

[a  1.1  2, b  0.1  2, g  2.3  1, f  1.1  5 .....]

I've seen some questions and answers with comparator but all of them are doing sort with one type of arraylist. But here I have 2 types of arraylist and I really don't know how to do it!

So if you have any idea please share it with me and if possible share some sample code.

I am a novice in stackoverflow as well as have not much experience in Java. I'm having a great trouble with this situation. After googling and searching particularly in stackoverflow but couldn't get any helpful idea to go through. I've explained the situation above and please pardon me if I made any mistake!

Thanks!

Comment: Is this homework? Oddly it sounds too odd to be homework too.

Comment: Are the strings in the 1st array a unique set or can there be 2 or more objects where their string properties are equal?

Comment: @user845279: no string property in 1st array is unique.

Comment: _"1st arraylist contains string and double"_ -- do you mean each element of th `ArrayList` is an object containing a `String` and `double` element?

Comment: @JimGarrison: yeah, exactly as you said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets assume the object in `list1` and `list2` are of type Foo and Bar and they both implement a method `getString()` which returns the string property. Like you said, the string values in list 1 are unique.

```
ArrayList<Foo> list1 = new ArrayList<Foo>();
ArrayList<Bar> list2 = new ArrayList<Bar>();

final HashMap<String, Integer> positions = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
for(int i=0;i<list1.size();i++){
    positions.put(obj.getString(), i);
}

Collections.sort(list2, new Comparator<Bar>(){
    public int compare(Bar obj1, Bar obj2){
        return positions.get(obj2.getString()) - positions.get(obj1.getString());
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is fairly simple.  Here's some pseudo-Java, which assumes there are no duplicate keys in `list1`, and does not require any external libraries.

Assuming the following...

```
class List1Item {
    String stringValue;
    double doubleValue;
};
class List2Item {
    String stringValue;
    double doubleValue;
    int    intValue;
};

List<List1Item> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
List<List2Item> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
```

The general approach is to build a mapping between each key value and its position in the first list.

```
// Map to hold list1 key-to-position association
Map<String,Integer> sortKeys = new HashMap<>();

// Populate the key-to-position map with keys from list1
int pos=0;
for (List1Item i : list1)
    sortKeys.put(i.stringValue,pos++);
```

Then use the map to sort `list2` items by the position of the key in `list1`:

```
// Define a comparator that will use the map to sort list2 keys
Comparator<List2Item> comp = new Comparator<List2Item>() 
{
    public int compare(List2Item v1, List2Item v2)
    {
        return sortKeys.get(v1.stringValue).compareTo(sortKeys.get(v2.stringValue));
    }
}
Collections.sort(list2,comp);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply! Your example works fine for my problem! :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty complicated problem, and there isn't going to be any truly simple solution.

The simplest thing I can think of depends on the third-party library [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/). (Disclosure: I am a contributor.)

Let's call the first object type `Foo` and the second object type `Bar`, since you haven't named them yet.  I'm also assuming that the `String` fields of the `Bar`s are *unique* in the second list.

```
List<String> stringOrder = new ArrayList<String>();
for (Bar bar : list2) {
  stringOrder.add(bar.getString());
}
Ordering<String> stringComparator = Ordering.explicit(stringOrder);
// construct a String comparator based on that ordering
Ordering<Foo> fooOrdering = stringComparator.onResultOf(
  new Function<Foo, String>() {
    public String apply(Foo foo) {
      return foo.getString();
    }
  });
Collections.sort(list1, fooOrdering);
```